# Apply a function to a list of data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, fourier-analysis

Im basically messing around with discrete Fourier-Transformation and I cant figure out how to apply it. I know there exists a predefined command, but I want to learn the computation behind it and im trying to figure out the details.

I have a list of data:

```
data=Table[{i,Sin[2*Pi*i/100]+Sin[2*Pi*i/25] + RandomReal[{-1,1}] },{i,100}];
```

And I have a function `F[k]` of the variable `k`. Which is defined like this:
`F[k]=Sum[{i=1,100},Exp[-I*k*i]*x[i]]` where `x[i]` is equal to `data[[i,2]]`.

I need help to `Plot` the function `F[k]`.

Comment: Read docs of [`Fourier`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html), see details section for definition and properties and relations section, it contains the formula you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in Sum. The sum is written like:

```
data = Table[{i, 
    Sin[2*Pi*i/100] + Sin[2*Pi*i/25] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 100}];
F[k_] := Sum[Exp[-I*k*i]*data[[i, 2]], {i, 1, 100}]
```

Now you can plot the real and imaginary part like:

```
Plot[Re@F[k], {k, 0, 2Pi}]
Plot[Im@F[k], {k, 0, 2Pi}]
```

[image]